# how to expand excel cell column width via plsql coding

Tags: plsql

In Oracle plsql, I convert my database table values to Excel format.

I converted successfully with customised color, header etc. but I cannot find out how to expand cell column width through coding?

Comment: How are you converting your tables to "Excel format"? Are you making a `SYLK` file or some other format? I can't imagine you generating a `.xlsx` or `.xls` file from pl/sql.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are outputting an XML based spreadsheet, you can achieve column widths using something like this:

```
htp.p   ('<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="104.25"/>');
```

This would need to be output after the Table node but before the Row node.

Comment: This helped me - Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

it you are using (or want to use) ORA_EXCEL, column width can be adjusted using procedure set_column_width.

In following example you can see how easy is to create Excel document and adjust columnsize with ORA_XCEL:

```
BEGIN    
    ORA_EXCEL.new_document;    
    ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('Sheet 1');  

    ORA_EXCEL.set_column_width('A', 30);  

    ORA_EXCEL.add_row;  
    ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('A', 'Custom column width');  
    ORA_EXCEL.save_to_file('EXPORT_DIR', 'example.xlsx');    
END;
```

More details you can find [here](http://www.oraexcel.com/examples/pl-sql-excel-set-column-width)

Cheers